# RandomizedSearchCV on specific data set

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want to perform a randomized search looking at the results against a specific part of the dataset (not using cross-validation).
The solution I use below seems to overfit, it is like adaboost uses the whole training set and then measures its accuracy against mask_hold (but it saw it while training).
Do you know what I am missing?

```
mask_hold = np.array(range(1000)) #dummy value
ada = AdaBoostRegressor(DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=max_depth))
ada_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(ada, param_dist, n_jobs=-1, cv=[(mask_hold,mask_hold)], n_iter=20, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')
ada_cv.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

Comment: I think you are correct, try `cv=[(mask_hold[:500], mask_hold[500:])]` instead. Also, you can use numpy native function for the array `mask_hold = np.arange(1000)`.

Comment: Seems to work but I don't understand why... Are we forced to have at least two CV?

Comment: It is quite simple. The list you are giving to cv is called folds, one for train, one for test. You were correct in assumption that you show the whole set to the model, so it achieves perfect accuracy on the same set.

Comment: Then I should show it cv = [ (~mask_hold, mask_hold) ] no? I don't want it to be trained on this mask_hold, just to be tested on it